# Laravel - sub query max of GROUP BY

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent

I need help in getting the max claim_id of a table that is grouped by claim_company_id in Laravel.

Here is the table sample:

```
claim_id         claim_company_id       Date
1                     1                  1/1/2010
2                     1                  1/2/2010
3                     7                  1/3/2010
4                     7                  1/4/2010
5                     7                  1/5/2010

SELECT * FROM `claims`
WHERE
claims.claim_id in (SELECT max(claim_id) from claims GROUP by claim_company_id)
```

The output should be

```
2 - 1 - 1/2/2010
5 - 7 - 1/5/2010
```

But when I run this query

```
$query = DB::table('claims')
    ->groupBy('claim_company_id')
    ->get([
        'claims.*',
        'claim_company_id',
        DB::raw('MAX(claim_id) as claim_id_new')
    ]);
```

The result is

```
1 - 1 - 1/1/2010
3 - 7 - 1/3/2010
```

I’m stuck for a day now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I needed to use whereRaw to run the code but turns out it works this way.
Answering for future reference

```
$query = DB::table('claims') 
             ->whereRaw('claim_id in (select max(claim_id) from claims group by (claim_company_id))')
             ->get();
```